# Content <div> background color is incorrect

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML page and the background color for the content  is not differentiating from the main body background color. I've been staring at this for over an hour and can't find the bug.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="twoColLiqLtHdr.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><!--[if lte IE 7]>
<style>
.content { margin-right: -1px; } /* this 1px negative margin can be placed on any of the columns in this layout with the same corrective effect. */
ul.nav a { zoom: 1; }  /* the zoom property gives IE the hasLayout trigger it needs to correct extra whiltespace between the links */
</style>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="header"><img src="logo.png" width="35%" height="90" style="background: #A9B92E; display:block;" /> 
    <!-- end .header --></div>

  <div class="sidebar1">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
      <li><a href="codebook.php">Tag Codebook</a></li>
      <li><a href="articleadmin.php">Article Admin.</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <!-- end .sidebar1 --></div>

  <div class="content">
      <form id="form" name="form" action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
        <h1>Edit Details for &nbsp; &nbsp;<?php echo $articletitle; ?></h1>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="6">
          <tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td colspan="2"><legend>Article details</legend></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="26%" align="right"><span class="field">Article Title</span></td>
            <td width="74%" align="left"><span class="field">
              <input name="articletitle" type="text" value="<?php echo $articletitle; ?>" size="50"/>
            </span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="field">Article Author</span></td>
            <td align="left"><span class="field">
              <input name="articleorganization" type="text" value="<?php echo $articleorganization; ?>" size="50"/>
            </span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="field">Article Date</span></td>
            <td align="left"><span class="field">
              <input name="articledate" type="text" value="<?php echo $articledate; ?>" size="50"/>
            </span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="field">Article Url:</span></td>
            <td align="left"><span class="field">
              <input name="articleurl" type="text" value="<?php echo $articleurl; ?>" size="50"/>
            </span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="right"><span class="field">Article Tags:</span></td>
            <td align="left"><span class="field">
              <input name="articletags" type="text" value="<?php echo $articletags; ?>" size="50"/>
            </span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr align="center" valign="middle">
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
          </div>
       </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <p>My Footer</p>
    <!-- end .footer --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not defining any background colours anywhere, are you? At least not in the code visible to us.

Comment: have you try debugging the html/css in google chrome, and seeing what values the css are being set to.

Comment: can you show the code in *twoColLiqLtHdr.css*?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed the error was likely in the HTML. The CSS is quite large, so I pasted it into Zerobin:  http://sebsauvage.net/paste/?0a6e9af51059c9a3#OYmIc4PgbIc7iqRqynE2dNrePwUVMXk9JQ9x7cHNxQw=

Comment: Would you mind posting a link to your site? It would be much easier to help if I could see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking on your CSS, you haven't define the background color for your content class

```
   .content {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
   }
```

I recommend you using **ID** rahter than **Class**, because your content div is unique.

**EDIT**

I think what you mean is why the div class container not showing it background-color = #FFF; ?
Sorry for mistaken your question, you should add in .container css.

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floats at this point - 
Add `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` in your code, where I have placed.

```
    </form>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>      
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UAbe9/1/